# Is there another way to find boolean in a list of lists?

Tags: python

EDIT: I have solved the issue by not formatting the boolean straight away, keeping it as a string for function3() and then formatting it after just before displaying the result. Thank You for your ideas, they were all pretty helpful!

I am writing a program which uses a .csv file and one of the colums only contains True or False. I format the text to be boolean so I need a way to extract only lists that contain True (the lists also contain integers and strings, so I wrote a function findinlist(thing). I am a beginner so I am struggling with getting this to work for boolean. When I run it it returns an empty list. Is there another way of doing it or do I have to make modifications to my function? When I try to extract strings with it it works.

Here is the function:

```
def findinlist(thing):
 global rowsfound
 rowsfound = []
 for sample in enddata:
   for element in sample:
    try:
      if thing in element:
             rowsfound.append(sample)
             break
    except TypeError:
        pass
 return rowsfound
```

(I am aware that using global is not very nice)

And here is how I use it

```
def option3():
    exceptionlist=findinlist(True)
    print(exceptionlist)
        break
    print("-"*80)
    menureturn()
```

I tried to use speech marks but obviously that would try to find a string and not a boolean.

EDIT: my csv file looks like this: 0    00:00   14  0   FALSE   0 
These are the columns before formatting, but I change columns 1,2 and 4 to string so they become 'sunday', '00:00', 14, 'none', False, 0 (the False becomes a boolean)

EDIT: I have also tried it with unformatted data (all strings) and it did find "True", however I would like to work with data already formatted to be a boolean.

Comment: something like `[sample for sample in enddata if any(sample)]`, or `if any(thing in element for element in sample)` according to your original code, which should probably be `if any(thing == element for element in sample)`

Comment: `csv` file cannot contain booleans. Once read, it only contains _strings_. It's unclear what you're asking but you'd be better off with `"True"` to start with

Comment: If your csv contains the string True, then you should pass your function 'True' rather than True, as the latter is a boolean python object

Comment: Why do you have `global rowsfound`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot that I format text after reading it! I format the string "True" t o be a boolean True.

Comment: Posting a sample of you csv file (or some mock data with the same structure) would be clearer. Could you do that ?

Comment: 0 00:00 14 0 FALSE 0   these are the columns before formatting, but I change columns 1,2 and 4 to string so they become 'sunday', '23:00', 16, 'none', False, 0   (the False becomes a boolean)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add lines of code that create a short sample `enddata` list—what it was before you changed it doesn't really matter.

Comment: It looks like the perfect case for using `pandas` but helping would be easier with several lines of your CSV **with the file header** if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def findinlist(thing):
    if type(thing) is bool:
        thing = str(thing)
    global rowsfound
    rowsfound = []
    for sample in enddata:
        for element in sample:
            try:
                if thing in element:
                    rowsfound.append(sample)
                    break
            except TypeError:
                pass
    return rowsfound
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below seems to work, although I don't understand why you made `rowsfound` a `list` because as soon as the first match is found, nothing else will be `append`ed to because of the `break` in the `for` loop.

```
def findinlist(thing):
    global rowsfound
    rowsfound = []
    for sample in enddata:
        if thing in sample:
            rowsfound.append(sample)
            break
    return rowsfound

enddata = [['sunday', '00:00', 14, 'none', False, 0],
           ['tuesday', '04:20', 42, 'one', True, 13],]

print(findinlist(True))  # -> [['tuesday', '04:20', 42, 'one', True, 13]]
```